# time complexity in shell sort

Tags: c, sorting, shellsort

Why time complexity is less in shell sort when compared to bubble sort and insertion sort? How can we calculate time complexity, I mean on what basis we consider our code is high or low time complexity?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void shellsort(int arr[], int num)
{
    int i, j, k, tmp;
    for (i = num / 2; i > 0; i = i / 2)
    {
        for (j = i; j < num; j++)
        {
            for (k = j - i; k >= 0; k = k - i)
            {
                if (arr[k + i] >= arr[k])
                    break;
                else
                {
                    tmp = arr[k];
                    arr[k] = arr[k + i];
                    arr[k + i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[30];
    int k, num;
    printf("Enter total no. of elements : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", num);
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[k]);
    }
    shellsort(arr, num);
    printf("\n Sorted array is: ");
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
        printf("%d ", arr[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: The asymptotic complexity of Shell sort is a tricky question whose answer depends on details of the implementation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort).  This is far broader a question than SO accepts.

Comment: code format, spelling/grammar

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question *on what basis we consider our code is high or low time complexity* a simple thing to consider for sorting algorithm with N elements is how many comparisons are made to make the array of elements sorted. The comparisons further lead to swapping of elements, which translates to more resources used on the system (CPU).

Bubble/insertion sort can end up with n^2 comparisons (can be optimized if no swaps are made then do not scan again for already sorted arrays). Shell sort was refined to do better than n^2 in certain scenarios.  The wikipedia pointers are a good reference but would suggest read up a book on algorithms specifically dealing with sorting to gain more clarity (Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis - Mark Allen Weiss or some others)